# Unable to Remove Checked Item from Table

Tags: html, angularjs

I am beginner to Angular JS and learning by creating test pages with out database connection. I created a sample app, where user enters ID & Full Name . Displaying registered data in table and up on selection of specific 
 check box , user must removed from table and user details.

**Problem:** when I checked 2nd one ( 102 user) and clicked delete button, 103 user is getting deleted. Am new to angular JS ,

**HTML:**

```
<div class="controls" ng-controller="myUSerSignupCtrl">
    <input class="controlsspace" ng-model="userid" ng-required="true" placeholder="Please Enter UserId" id="txtUserID" type="text" />
    <input class="controlsspace" ng-required="true" placeholder="Please Enter FullName" ng-model="fullname" id="txtFullName" type="text" />
    <button style="height: 25px;" id="Submit1" ng-click="addNew()">REGISTER</button>

<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <th>UserId</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>    
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in userDetails">
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="user.selected" ng-model="editdeleteuserid" ng-click="selectEachCheckbox(user.userid)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            {{user.userid}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{user.fullname | uppercase}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
//Each Checkbox Slection.
$scope.selectEachCheckbox = function (userid) {
    $scope.selectAllCheckboxes = false;
    var idx = selectedIds.indexOf(userid);
    if (selectedIds.indexOf(userid) == -1) {
        selectedIds.push(userid);
    } else {
        selectedIds.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    $scope.btnEditShowHide = false;
    $scope.btnDelteHideShow = true;

    if (selectedIds.length == 0){
        $scope.btnDelteHideShow = false;
    }
    if(selectedIds.length == 1){
        $scope.btnEditShowHide = true;
    }
};

//Delete Click Button
$scope.DeleteUSers = function () {
    var newDataList = $scope.userDetails;
    for(i=0;i<selectedIds.length;i++){
        var id = selectedIds[i];
        var index = $scope.userDetails.indexOf(id)
        $scope.userDetails.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $scope.userDetails = newDataList;
    selectedIds = [];
    $scope.selectAllCheckboxes = false;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The code can be greatly simplified if you utilize the model binding power of AngularJs.

The idea is recording the checkbox selection inside the data array itself using `ng-model`, when deleting filter the data array to purge selected items.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {id: 1, name: 'apple'},
    {id: 2, name: 'banana'},
    {id: 3, name: 'orange'},
    {id: 4, name: 'pear'}
  ];

  $scope.delete = function() {
    var deletedIds = $scope.items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.selected;
    }).map(function(item) {
      return item.id;
    });
    
    $scope.deleted = "deleting id [" + deletedIds.join(",") + "]";
    
    $scope.items = $scope.items.filter(function(item) {
      return !item.selected;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" />
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  
  <button type="button" ng-click="delete()">delete</button>
  <div>{{deleted}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: lcycool@: Thanks for your suggestion, but my requirement is having more than 5 columns in table( userid, fullname,mobile,email,address etc.,) .Also i have checkbox in table header. So if user clicks table header checkbox, automatically all check boxes should be checked or if user manually checked specific checkbox should be checked( I had already implemented this)  . Now when i click delete button, I need to find index of table ( i would like to know for which user id i checked) , such that i can delete from table. Unique column is Userid.

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS I've updated to demonstrate how to get id from data itself upon delete. Keeping track of checked id can work, but it requires more complicated logic, imo it's better to make the code simple and maintainable.